# Query SQL retorna dados que não eram pra serem retornados

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-eloquent

Bom, estou montando um sisteminha de venda de ingressos para partidas de futebol como projeto do meu curso estou trabalhando com o Laravel + Eloquent ORM, porém estou com uma inconsistência.

Meu código é:

```
$matches = Match::select('ut_matches.id', 'ut_matches.id_championship', 'ut_matches.id_stadium','ut_matches.id_club_main','ut_matches.id_club_visitor','ut_matches.id_match_round', 'ut_matches.date_match', 'ut_matches.schedule_match', 'ut_lots.id AS id_lot','ut_lots.tickets_sell', 'ut_lots.price_full', 'ut_lots.id_stadium_sector','ut_stadiums_sectors.name AS sector_name', 'ut_stadiums.name', 'ut_stadiums.id_club', 'ut_stadiums.id_state', 'ut_stadiums.id_city')
 ->join('ut_lots', 'ut_lots.id_match', 'ut_matches.id')
 ->join('ut_stadiums_sectors', 'ut_lots.id_stadium_sector', 'ut_stadiums_sectors.id')
 ->join('ut_stadiums', 'ut_stadiums_sectors.id_stadium', 'ut_stadiums.id')
 ->where('ut_lots.id_lot_status', 2)
 ->where('ut_matches.date_match', '>', date('Y-m-d', strtotime(now())))
 ->where('ut_matches.id_club_main', Auth::user()->id_club)
 ->orWhere('ut_matches.id_club_visitor', Auth::user()->id_club)
 ->orderBy('ut_matches.date_match', 'DESC')
 ->groupBy('ut_matches.id')
 ->limit(6)
 ->get();
```

Todo este código me gera:

```
 select `ut_matches`.`id`, `ut_matches`.`id_championship`, `ut_matches`.`id_stadium`, `ut_matches`.`id_club_main`, `ut_matches`.`id_club_visitor`, `ut_matches`.`id_match_round`, `ut_matches`.`date_match`, `ut_matches`.`schedule_match`, `ut_lots`.`id` as `id_lot`, `ut_lots`.`tickets_sell`, `ut_lots`.`price_full`, `ut_lots`.`id_stadium_sector`, `ut_stadiums_sectors`.`name` as `sector_name`, `ut_stadiums`.`name`, `ut_stadiums`.`id_club`, `ut_stadiums`.`id_state`, `ut_stadiums`.`id_city` from `ut_matches` inner join `ut_lots` on `ut_lots`.`id_match` = `ut_matches`.`id` inner join `ut_stadiums_sectors` on `ut_lots`.`id_stadium_sector` = `ut_stadiums_sectors`.`id` inner join `ut_stadiums` on `ut_stadiums_sectors`.`id_stadium` = `ut_stadiums`.`id` where `ut_matches`.`date_match` > '2019-07-24' and `ut_lots`.`id_lot_status` = 2 and `ut_matches`.`id_club_main` = 1 or `ut_matches`.`id_club_visitor` = 1 and `ut_matches`.`deleted_at` is null group by `ut_matches`.`id` order by `ut_matches`.`date_match` desc limit 6
```

Só que o problema é que ele gera uma inconsistência por conta de dois where, porém eu preciso tê-los.

```
 ->where('ut_matches.id_club_main', Auth::user()->id_club)
 ->orWhere('ut_matches.id_club_visitor', Auth::user()->id_club)
```

Ou seja, eu preciso verificar qual é o time do usuário cadastrado, mas também preciso verificar se a data do jogo não ultrapassou a data atual:

```
 ->where('ut_matches.date_match', '>', date('Y-m-d', strtotime(now())))
```

Se eu remover os meus dois wheres de buscar o clube do usuário funciona o where da data, mas eu preciso ter estar 3 cláusulas. Como posso fazer o meu select para não gerar essa inconsistente?

Comment: Qual é a inconsistência?

Comment: É que está sendo desconsiderado o where da data da partida

Comment: Como estão armazenados os registros da coluna `date_match`. Você consegue fornecer essa informação?

Comment: `date_match` é uma coluna que armazena no formato `Y-m-d` tipo `date`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A incoerência no resultado se deve ao fato que as datas estão sendo comparadas como strings. Logo a data `2019-07-24` é **menor** que `2019-06-30` seguindo este modelo de comparação.

Para comparar as datas em tipo `DATE` no Laravel existem diversas possibilidades.

Utilizar a própria função do Query Builder, `whereDate`:

```
->whereDate('ut_matches.date_match', '>', date('Y-m-d'))
```

Concatenar o *time* com a data:

```
->where('ut_matches.date_match', '>', date('Y-m-d') . ' 00:00:00')
```

Usar as função `DATE()` do MySQL:

```
->whereRaw("DATE(ut_matches.date_match) > '" . date('Y-m-d') . "'")
```

> Para utilizar a função `DATE()` ou outras funções do MySQL, é necessário inseri-las como strings e para isso existem as "[raw expressions](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#raw-expressions)"

---

Para conhecer a grande quantidade de funções para a cláusula `where`, veja na própria [documentação](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#where-clauses) do Laravel.